# WPF - How to create 3D Models with Code Behind (similar to old Autocad)

Tags: wpf, 3d, code-behind

I see lot of 3D Editors for WPF, where users can create some 3D models very easily, but I am looking for something that would allow me to create 3D Models from Code Behind. Kind of first autocad versions, I remember when I was student I used it and all was done with command lines, something like that :

AddRectangle (X0, Y0, Z0, DX, DY, DZ)
RemoveRectangle(X0, Y0, Z0, DX, DY, DZ)
AddCylinder(X0, Y0, Z0, DX, DY, DZ,Radius)

Concrete code, to make a rectangle plate with a 20mm hole inside

AddRectangle (0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 10)
AddCylinder(50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 10,20)

Are such library existing? Cause I am looking on 3D documentations, and very "heavy job" to work on circular shapes (well for now I am trying to display a cube yet).

Comment: Combination of simple 3D Framework (like Helixtoolkit) and some related Model-level classes would do the job: create your own `Cylinder` class that will wrap a real 3D WPF Element based on simple parameters.

Comment: Yet, building an *Autocad* like software, including boolean operations would be much more tricky :P

Comment: I would search for `CAD Control. NET` on Google and pick the tool you like more.

Comment: P.Manthe I think that's not so simple, regarding information I read already about drawing 3D, you cannot "remove" a 3D shape from another, you create only surfaces and that's all, about making a Autocad like I guess you are joking :) ... will try with key words given by abenci

Comment: P.Manthe my apologies :). I didn't think Helix allowed that kind of things, but seems I was wrong... I think I need to look in that way, even the documentation seems very poor